# Cannot match any routes while want to navigate to a page

Tags: angular

He guys

Im new in Angular,in my login page i want if the login is  successful redirect to the component page which i have shown below:

```
  this.router.navigate(['/overview.component.html']);
```

Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'overview.component.html'

my overview component is :

```
selector: 'app-overview',
templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
```

should not i write the templateurl in the navigation?if so,why does it give me the error?

here is my module.ts

```
    RouterModule.forRoot([
                   
                      {path:'',component:LoginComponent},
                      {path:'app-events',component:EventsComponent},
                      {path:'app-turbine-comparison',component:TurbineComparisonComponent}

 ]),
```

Comment: Could you share what is included in your routing module? What are the routes you have defined? Does it correspond to the route you are trying to navigate to above?

Comment: @Musilix is right. We need to see your routing module.

Comment: @Ross  updated my question

Comment: @Musilix updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this route to your routing module:

```
  RouterModule.forRoot([            
    {path:'',component:LoginComponent},
    {path:'app-events',component:EventsComponent},
    {path:'app-turbine-comparison',component:TurbineComparisonComponent}

    //Add additional route here
    {path:'app-overview', AppOverviewComponent},
 ]),
```

And then navigate to it like this:

```
  this.router.navigate(['/app-overview']);
```